# Kotlin Wi-Fi loss/bad signal during FTP transfer

Tags: kotlin, android-wifi, connectivity

I'm nearly done creating an app that sends txt files, containing scanned data, to an ftp server.
The issue that I'm currently struggling with is: what if my Wi-Fi has terrible signal or no signal at all.

I noticed that my 'isOnline()' check works fine and that if there is no internet, it alerts the user. However a few hours ago I tested the app in the basement and noticed that when the Wi-Fi signal has no bars, it still sends the data but it gets lost somewhere along the way.
Currently the flow of the data is as follow:

1. user presses 'send'
2. check internet and if true, continue
3. clear content list and send
   the content to viewmodel
4. viewmodel checks internet again before
   creating the txt files
5. txt files get sent via FTP code below.

```kotlin
    private fun sendTXT(result: String) {
        try {
            val name = "00_VER${LocalDateTime.now().format(fileNameFormatter)}.txt"
            val path = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext.filesDir.path
                .toString() + name
            val f = File(path)
            val isNewFileCreated: Boolean = f.createNewFile()
            if (isNewFileCreated) {
                f.writeText(result, Charsets.UTF_8)
            }

            val ftpClient = FTPClient()
            ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(PrintCommandListener(PrintWriter(System.out)))
            ftpClient.connect("xxx.xx.xxx.xx", 21)
            val reply: Int = ftpClient.replyCode
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftpClient.disconnect()
                throw IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server")
            }
           
            if (ftpClient.login("username", "pass")) {
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
                val inp = FileInputStream(f)
                var directory = "/files/input"
                ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(directory)
                val result = ftpClient.storeFile(name, inp)
                inp.close()
                if (result) {
                    ftpClient.logout()
                    ftpClient.disconnect()
                    f.delete()
                }

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
    fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
        var result = false
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val actNw =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
            result = when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            connectivityManager.run {
                connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    result = when (type) {
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                        else -> false
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return result

    }
```

I'm stuck at finding a way to make sure the data gets to the server. Is there a more advanced way to check for internet connectivity?
I was considering adding all the scan objects as JSON to sharedpreferences, and if at the end of the day the user notices a scan didn't make it through, they can look up the missing scan and resend it.
However this seems very unconventional and I'm pretty sure there must be a better way to handle things.

Comment: I don't know about the connectivity issues, but have you considered doing a directory listing after the transfer, to check that the file is present on the site and the correct size?  (For extra safety, you could download the file and compare it with the original, but that might be overkill.)